# Having trouble with the manager functionality in django

Tags: django, django-models

Designing code to handle transfers of objects called "contractBundles". Have this in the models.py in a "contract" app:

```
class contractBundleManager():
 #   def trade(self, buyer, seller, amount):
     def add (self, user=pgamedb_models.Player, contractName=str, amount=float):
         contractList = contract.objects.all()
         for c in contractList:
             if contractName == c.contractText:
                 user.money = user.money - (amount * c.value)
                 return self.create(contract=c, volume=amount, owner=user)

class contractBundle(models.Model):
    objects = contractBundleManager()

    contract = models.ForeignKey('contract')
    volume = models.FloatField()
    owner = models.ForeignKey(pgamedb_models.Player)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%10.2f x %s -> %s' % (self.volume, self.contract.shortName, self.owner.user.username)
```

Elsewhere, I want to let people purchase the bundles by pressing a button:

```
from contracts import models as cmodels
...
 if request.method == 'POST':
          ...
        elif 'Buy' in request.POST:
            [set up activeUser, polName, amount]
            cmodels.contractBundle.objects.add(user=activeUser, contractName=polName, amount=amount)
```

Yet when the code calls the `contractBundle.objects.add()` method, I get the following error:

```
AttributeError at [url]
'Manager' object has no attribute 'add'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    [url]
Django Version: 1.3.1
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'Manager' object has no attribute 'add'
Exception Location: ...views.py in [method], line 56
Python Executable:  /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
Python Version: 2.7.1
```

Any thoughts why this might be happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of things here that are wrong.

Firstly, your manager class needs to inherit from models.Manager:

```
class contractBundleManager(models.Manager):
```

This is where all the code like `create` is defined.

Also, it seems like a really bad idea to use classes/types as default values for function parameters. If you want to document what types a function needs, you should use a docstring.

**Edit after comment** No, I'm not referring to the return statement or the way you're calling  `self.create`. I'm referring to the default values in the `contractBundleManager.add` method. You should never do this. If someone calls your method without passing the `user` parameter, the function will use the default value you have defined - which is a class.  Classes in Python are mutable, so your function will actually modify the definition of the `Player` class.

Really, this is not the way to show the correct types to call the function with. Leave out the default values, and use a docstring.

Comment: _Also, it seems like a really bad idea to use classes/types as default values for function parameters._

I assume that you're referring to `return self.create(contract=c, volume=amount, owner=user)`? Why is this poor form?

Answer (score 1):

```
#model
class contractBundle(models.Model):
    objects = models.Manager( )
    contact_bundle_manager = contractBundleManager( )
#view
cmodels.contact_bundle_manager.add(user=activeUser, contractName=polName, amount=amount)
```

Comment: Thanks, that moved it forward but now it's telling me that there's no attribute "create" -- shouldn't this be hard-wired in for all objects?